# Android after Capture image from camera restarting the Activity

Tags: android, android-studio, image-upload

After Capture image through camera and get back to the activity to save the image in local storage and show in the view, But in some times it recreate the activity. Kindly help on this for solution, Thanks in Advance

Comment: This is [specifically called out as a possibility in the documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result#register): "When starting an activity for a result, it is possible—and, in cases of memory-intensive operations such as camera usage, almost certain—that your process and your activity will be destroyed due to low memory."

Comment: What was the Solution for this?